# Setting up Mosquitto with SSL

Tags: mosquitto

I'm trying to set-up Mosquitto with SSL on my Raspberry Pi 3.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2017/09/mqtt-security-securing-mosquitto-server.html)

Now my mosquitto.conf is:

```
listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosq-ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosq-serv.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosq-serv.key
```

But when I run the commend:

```
mosquitto_sub -t "#" -v --cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosq-ca.crt -p 8883
```

I get:

```
Error: connection refused
```

I have deleted the `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/mosquitto.conf`. The file is now empty. The default mosquitto.conf now is:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid 
persistence true persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/ 
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log 
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d 
listener 8883 
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosq-ca.crt 
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosq-serv.crt 
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mosq-serv.key
```

But I still receive

```
Error: connection refused
```

What did I do wrong or what did I forget to do?

When i use ( i wont listen on port 8883) `sudo mosquitto -v`:

```
1514921332: mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date Mon, 29 May 2017 13:43:29 +0100) starting
1514921332: Using default config.
1514921332: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1514921332: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
```

My `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` log:

```
 1514932164: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
    1514932164: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
    1514932164: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
    1514932373: Error in poll: Interrupted system call.
    1514932373: mosquitto version 1.4.10 terminating
    1514932378: mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date Mon, 29 May 2017 13:43:29 +010$
```

The Error has thanged to: `Error: A TLS error occurred.`

Comment: For future reference, I'd not use self-signed certificates which are not trusted unless explicitly whitelisted. Instead, I'd use a free [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) certificate (like see https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-ssl-lets-encrypt).

Answer (score 5):

As has been suggested in the comments (and now verified by log output) your `mosquitto.conf` file is not being used.

You need to specify the config file when starting the broker with the `-c` command line argument.

```
mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

Mosquitto will **NOT** default to the /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf, if no file is passed it will only listen on port 1883 with no SSL.

If you are starting the broker as a service at startup then you need to check the `/etc/init.d/mosquitto` script to ensure it is passing the config file to mosquitto when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

This should work
Seeing what you are doing, I believe you will use the server.crt and server.key to authenticate Login I guess ?
Then you would need need another line in the `mosquitto.conf` ie.

`require_certificate` which when set to be `true` will ask the incoming clients to provide certificates